# Can I setup a docker overlay network without using docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have two sets of services (groups of containers) running on two different machines. Both sets of services are declared using a docker-compose file. Currently, in each docker-compose file, I am including a bridge network. These two sets of services communicate with each other by explicitly mentioning the IP addresses of each machine.

1. If I have these two docker service sets communicating with each other over an overlay network instead of having each set communicating with each other by hard coding the IP addresses like I a have now, would this decrease network latency? In other words, would improve the performance of communication between these two services?
2. If the answer to the previous question is yes, then can I define an overlay network between these two machines without using a docker swarm? Also, can I declare this docker-swarm network within the docker-compose files?

If you have .yaml configuration files or command-line code snippets that would do what I want that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will an overlay network reduce latency?

Most likely no, it adds an additional layer of encapsulation for the IP packets that needs to be processed on each side of the connection. Typically people use the overlay networking to simplify the inter cluster communication and reduce complexity of service discovery (apps can communicate by service name, without looking up an external IP/port on another node.

> Do you need Swarm Mode for overlay?

No, but it makes it much easier, to the point that I wouldn't go back to the old way of running an external key/value db like consul and integrating docker with that. You also can't mix the old way of configuring overlay network databases with swarm mode, so if you decided to use swarm in the future, you'd need to disable the older k/v database configuration and recreate your overlay networks.

Swarm mode is extremely easy to enable:

```
docker swarm init
```

Then follow the instructions to either rerun the init command with needed flags like a network interface, or to join other nodes to the cluster.

Importantly, your containers themselves do not need to be managed by swarm mode, you can leave that to only manage the k/v database for overlay networking. When you create the network, make sure to set it to attachable to allow containers outside of swarm mode to use it:

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable overlay-net-name
```

You can also define that in the compose file, just be sure to specify the network name, and typically that will be external for the services started later.